# I have wrong result in my ANTLR Grammar

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar in ANTLR and I have a file for testing my grammar.
But I don't know what is wrong with my output.

This is my grammar:

```
grammar proj;

start
    : (assign|define|read|write|condition|while|module|callingmodule)+
    ;

assign
    : T_ID T_ENTESAB expentesab T_SEPARATOR
    ;

expentesab
    : T_ID
    | T_NUMBER
    | T_SABETMANTEGHI
    | expentesab operator expentesab
    | expentesab operator
    | operator expentesab
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expentesab T_PARANTEZBASTE
    | expentesab T_COMMA expentesab
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expentesab T_COMMA expentesab T_PARANTEZBASTE
    | expentesab T_COMMA T_PARANTEZBAZ expentesab T_PARANTEZBASTE
    ;

operator
    : T_ADD
    | T_SUB
    | T_MUL
    | T_DIV
    | T_POW
    | T_FACT
    | T_AND
    | T_OR
    | T_XOR
    ;

define
    : T_ID T_2POINT T_TYPE T_SEPARATOR
    ;

read
    : T_READ expread T_SEPARATOR
    ;

expread
    : T_ID
    | T_NUMBER
    | operator
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expread T_PARANTEZBASTE
    | expread operator expread
    ;

write
    : T_WRITE expwrite T_SEPARATOR
    ;

expwrite
    : T_ID
    | T_NUMBER
    | operator
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expwrite T_PARANTEZBASTE
    | expwrite operator expwrite
    | expwrite T_COMPARE expwrite  
    ;

condition
    : T_IF expcon T_THEN code_if T_ELSE code_if T_SEPARATOR
    | T_IF expcon T_THEN code_if T_SEPARATOR
    ;

expcon
    : assign
    | define
    | expcon T_COMPARE expcon
    | expcon operator expcon
    | operator expcon
    ;

code_if
    : condition
    | block
    | define
    | assign
    | callingmodule
    | code_if operator code_if
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ code_if T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ code_if operator code_if T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    ;

callingmodule
    : T_ID T_PARANTEZBAZ params T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    | T_ID T_PARANTEZBAZ  T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    ;

params
    : expparam(T_COMMA expparam)*
    ;

expparam
    : T_ID
    | shart
    | T_ID operator T_NUMBER
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expparam T_PARANTEZBASTE
    ;

while
    : T_WHILE expwhile code_while
    ;

expwhile
    : T_SABETMANTEGHI
    | T_NUMBER
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ expwhile T_PARANTEZBASTE
    | expwhile operator expwhile
    | T_ID T_COMPARE T_ID
    | expwhile T_AND expwhile
    | expwhile T_OR expwhile
    | expwhile T_XOR expwhile      
    ;  

code_while 
    : block
    | module
    | callingmodule
    | define
    | assign
    | code_while operator code_while T_SEPARATOR
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ code_while T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ code_while operator code_while T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    ;
        
block
    : T_BEGIN  inner_block  T_END
    ;

inner_block
    : define
    | assign
    | condition 
    | callingmodule
    | block
    | T_ID operator T_ID
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ inner_block T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    | T_PARANTEZBAZ T_ID operator T_ID T_PARANTEZBASTE T_SEPARATOR
    ;

module
    : T_MODULE T_ID T_INPUT T_2POINT (define)+ T_OUTPUT T_2POINT T_TYPE block
    | T_MODULE T_ID block 
    ;

shart
    : expcon T_CONDITION code_if T_2POINT code_if
    | expcon T_CONDITION code_if T_2POINT code_if T_SEPARATOR
    ;
        
T_TYPE: ('s'|'S')('t'|'T')('r'|'R')('i'|'I')('n'|'N')('g'|'G')|('r'|'R')('e'|'E')('a'|'A')('l'|'L')|
('b'|'B')('o'|'O')('o'|'O')('l'|'L');
T_END: ('e'|'E')('n'|'N')('d'|'D');
T_BEGIN:('b'|'B')('e'|'E')('g'|'G')('i'|'I')('n'|'N');
T_WHILE:('w'|'W')('h'|'H')('i'|'I')('l'|'L')('e'|'E');
T_IF:('i'|'I')('f'|'F');
T_THEN:('t'|'T')('h'|'H')('e'|'E')('n'|'N');
T_ELSE:('e'|'E')('l'|'L')('s'|'S')('e'|'E');
T_READ:('r'|'R')('e'|'E')('a'|'A')('d'|'D');
T_WRITE:('w'|'W')('r'|'R')('i'|'I')('t'|'T')('e'|'E');
T_MODULE:('M'|'m')('O'|'o')('D'|'d')('U'|'u')('L'|'l')('E'|'e');
T_INPUT:('I'|'i')('N'|'n')('P'|'p')('U'|'u')('T'|'t');
T_OUTPUT:('O'|'o')('U'|'u')('T'|'t')('P'|'p')('U'|'u')('T'|'t');
T_RETURN:('R'|'r')('E'|'e')('T'|'t')('U'|'u')('R'|'r')('N'|'n');
T_SEPARATOR : ';';
T_SABETMANTEGHI: ('t'|'T')('r'|'R')('u'|'U')('e'|'E')|('f'|'F')('a'|'A')('l'|'L')('s'|'S')('e'|'E');
T_NUMBER:T_HEXNUMBER|T_INTEGERNUMBER;
T_HEXNUMBER: '0' ('x'|'X') ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')+|'0' ('x'|'X') ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')+ '.' ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F')+;
T_INTEGERNUMBER:(('0'..'9')+|('0'..'9')+ '.'('0'..'9')+);
T_FUNC:('F'|'f')('U'|'u')|('N'|'n')('C'|'c');
T_ADD: '+';
T_SUB: '-';
T_MUL: '*';
T_DIV: '/';
T_POW: '^';
T_FACT: '!';
T_ENTESAB:'=';
T_X:'x'|'X';
T_AND: ('a'|'A')('n'|'N')('d'|'D');
T_OR: ('o'|'O')('r'|'R');
T_NOT: ('n'|'N')('o'|'O')('t'|'T');
T_XOR: ('x'|'X')('o'|'O')('r'|'R');
T_COMPARE: '>'| '<'| '>='|'<='|  '<>';
T_REMAIN: '%';
T_CONDITION:'?';
T_2POINT:':';
T_PARANTEZBAZ:'(';
T_PARANTEZBASTE:')';
T_COMMA:',';
T_COMMENT:T_COM1LINE|T_COMMULLINE;
T_COM1LINE: '%%' ~( '\t'|'\r')+ -> skip ;
T_COMMULLINE:'%%%' (.|('\t'|'\r'|' '|'\n'))*? '%%%' ->skip;
T_ID :   [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z]|('0'..'9'))*;
T_WS : (('\t'|'\r'|' ')+) ->skip;
T_NEWLINE:('\n')->skip;
T_LEXICALERROR:.;
```

And this is my input file:

```
%%%This is a sample Written in QUPLA $
@The program compute fibonacci serie%%%
module func
input:
    X:real;
output:
  i:real;
begin
    if x> 0 then
    begin 
        return Func(x-1)+func(x-2);
    end
    begin
    return 1;
    end
end
%% This is the main module &%*&()
module main
begin
    i:real;
    read i;
    write (func(i)?1:2);
end
```

For this input, I have these errors:

> In line 5 expecting T_ID   but i have T_ID!
>
> In line 8 expecting T_IF,T_WHILE T_READ....   But I have T_IF

Comment: I don't see the ID token anywhere. Is this your whole grammar?

Comment: T_ID :   [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z]|('0'..'9'))*;

Comment: `In line 5 expecting T_ID but i have ID!` What is `ID`? - EDIT: OK, I see the edit now - makes even less sense...

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your errors.

### Answers

> In line 5 expecting T_ID but i have T_ID!

This error is due the fact that you have lexer rule `T_X:'x'|'X';` which will match to the `X` from line 5 of your sample code. `X` will be match to `T_X` lexem because `T_X` lexem is defined before expected `T_ID` lexem. The answer is: ***it is not a T_ID token but T_X***.

> In line 8 expecting T_IF,T_WHILE T_READ.... But I have T_IF

In line 7 from code example you are trying to define an output variable `i:real`. But you are missing of `define+` rule in an output section of a `module` definition. I assume you can have named output parameter. Then proper `module` rule should looks like as follow:

```
module
    : T_MODULE T_ID T_INPUT T_2POINT define+ T_OUTPUT T_2POINT define+ T_TYPE block
    | T_MODULE T_ID  block
    ;
```

Because of missing `define+` the definition of `module` rule is interrupted and everything after `output:` in line 6 is treated as definition (`define`) alternative from main rule `start`.

If above it's not the case and your code example is wrong then you should remove `i:` characters in the `output` section of the module.

Anyway, the answer is: ***code example is inconsistent with your grammar***.

### Modifications

#### Rearange your tokens

You should define your tokens in an order:

1. Skipped tokens (e.g. whitespaces, comments)
2. Specialized tokens (e.g. keywords, operators, literals)
3. General tokens (e.g. identifier)

#### Pay attention to rule naming

You can't use names reserved to a language you use ANTLRv4 with. You defined `while` grammar rule which will raise conflict with `while` keyword in Java.

#### Readability and simplicity is the key

Use pleasent to eye and simpler ANTLRv4 constructs:

- Change `T_WS : (('\t'|'\r'|' ')+) ->skip;` to `T_WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;`
- Change `T_ID :   [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z]|('0'..'9'))*;` to `T_ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;`
- Change `T_COMMULLINE:'%%%' (.|('\t'|'\r'|' '|'\n'))*? '%%%' ->skip;` to `T_COMMULLINE:'%%%' .*? '%%%' -> skip;` (the dot `.` will match everything anyway, especially whitespace characters)